# Sql server session state problem

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I am developing a shopping cart website.

The problem is, when I add product items to my shopping cart and another user in another computer browses the shopping cart, suddenly has my cart details!!.

We have our site on a web farm, hence session state is held in Sql Server.
This is the first time I am setting up SessionState on Sql Server.

In my web.config I have this,

```
<sessionState
mode="SQLServer"
sqlConnectionString="data source=someip;user=someuser;password=somepassword"
cookieless="false"
timeout="20" />
```

Am I missing any thing? Help much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it is problem with session state?

Answer (score 2):

Session state is handled on a per browser instance basis whether InProc or not.  You have some other issue going on.

Answer (score 0):

Neil and rick, thanks for your response. 
The problem was not in session state. It was a static class stored with values was moving around and causing this confusion.